# OpenGL Shader errors (storage qualifiers, undeclared identifiers and float conversions)

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I'm starting out with OpenGL and have made my first shaders (following [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8n1GV99FJ2Y)). Despite following the tutorial to the letter, I got a few errors (unlike the tutorial-giver).

Despite thorough and inventive googling, I have found no help or explaination of what's going wrong.

The source for my shaders is as follows:

basicVertex.vs:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}



basicFragment.fs:

#version 330

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() 
{
    fragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
}
```

and the errors are as follows:

```
Shader could not be run: 
ERROR: 0:? : '' : storage qualifier not valid with layout qualifier id 
ERROR: 0:7: 'gl_Position' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:7: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of float' to 'float'
```

(that is the entire command-line output).

Here's the Shader loading/compilation code:

package uk.co.gossfunkel.citadel3d.shader;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL32.*;

public class Shader {
        private int program;

```
    public Shader() throws ShaderLoadException {
            program = glCreateProgram();

            if (program == 0) {
                    throw new ShaderLoadException();
            }
    }

    public void bind() {
            glUseProgram(program);
    }

    public void addVertexShader(String text) throws ShaderLoadException {
            addProgram(text, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    }

    public void addGeometryShader(String text) throws ShaderLoadException {
            addProgram(text, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
    }

    public void addFragmentShader(String text) throws ShaderLoadException {
            addProgram(text, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    }

    public void compileShader() throws ShaderLoadException {
            glLinkProgram(program);

            if (glGetProgrami(program, GL_LINK_STATUS) == 0) {
                    throw new ShaderLoadException(glGetShaderInfoLog(program, 1024));
            }

            glValidateProgram(program);

            if (glGetProgrami(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == 0) {
                    throw new ShaderLoadException(glGetShaderInfoLog(program, 1024));
            }
    }

    private void addProgram(String text, int type) throws ShaderLoadException {
            int shader = glCreateShader(type);
            if (shader == 0) {
                    throw new ShaderLoadException();
            }
            glShaderSource(shader, text);
            glCompileShader(shader);

            if (glGetShaderi(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0) {
                    throw new ShaderLoadException(glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024));
            }

            glAttachShader(program, shader);
    }
```

}

If anyone can direct me to solutions or suggest what's wrong, I'd love to hear it. However, please don't just say "learn more OpenGL", as that isn't helpful. Thanks!

Comment: How are you building it? Where's your shader compilation code?

Comment: building it in java, i've now posted the shader build class.

Comment: Could you put that in your question, rather than on some other site?

Comment: It's more lengthy, I usually get asked to link to longer code segments. I'll pop it in.

Comment: `fragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);` is only supplying 3 components.

Comment: True. I've added the fourth and it's still throwing the same errors.